# Securing Jersey based REST service using oAuth 2.0

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, oauth-2.0

I have created RESTful services in java/netbeans using the Jersey Library. Now i want to secure this service using oAuth 2.0.

Are there any libraries or any tutorial to achieve that? I couldn't find anything useful in google.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use Apache Oltu (formerly Apache Amber): https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OLTU/Documentation

The Authorization Server and Resource Server sections explain how to secure your REST services.

Comment: The link only provides code snippets for servlets. They have given [Integration Tests](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/amber/trunk/oauth-2.0/oauth2-integration-tests/) but the link doesnot work. 

Any complete example code for Jersey based service?

Answer (score 10):

Check this example Jersey + Oltu + Oauth:
https://bitbucket.org/dobromyslov/oauth2-example/src/

Explanation how it works is located here:

http://www.jasondl.ee/posts/2013/a-simple-oauth2-client-and-server-example-part-i.html

And here:

http://www.jasondl.ee/posts/2013/a-simple-oauth2-client-and-server-example-part-ii.html

Answer (score 1):

We used spring security, think is the simple and easiest way, look [here](http://www.springsource.org/spring-security-oauth) for more information:

Comment: does it work with jersey or only with spring mvc web services?

Comment: @shem do you have an example of how to do it?

Comment: To use jersey with spring, use the `ContextLoaderListener`